# How to get a good start on being a CEO?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Alright, so I am just starting to want to be a CEO in Grand Theft Auto Online and I was wondering, how do I get a good start to this job? I will have a total of 1,450,000 (or maybe slightly above, just a couple hundreds above if so), and will this be enough to get a good start on being a CEO? Will I NEED more money, or will that be enough in the beginning? What will I need to do to get started on being a CEO and increasing my money amounts, warehouses, etc.

Comment: I consider this a game strategy question and think that it should be left open.

Answer (score 2):

Alright. To start off, you are going to want quite a large amount of money. The cheapest CEO building cost around $1M, so seeing as you say you have about $1.4M, you should be able to get it and still have a large amount of money left over. If you want to get a gun rack and safe, however, this will increase the price of the property you are buying. I suggest not buying those unless you are able to buy some more money or get it with missions, because you will need the extra money to buy warehouses and crates for items to sell later, etc. Hope this will help, and good luck on being a CEO on GTA Online, and  I hope you do well and get some good associates to work with (yes you will probably want those).

Comment: Wow, lot's of help there! Makes sense though. Any more opinions would be great on how to get a good start as a CEO, and any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks again Frankenyuyu!